# Weird behavior in react hooks useEffect and ref object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning hooks and facing the following issue with ref object. When running this snippet:

```
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [maxX, setMaxX] = useState(0);
  const itemRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (itemRef.current.childElementCount > 0) {
      setMaxX((itemRef.current.childElementCount / 3) * 
      itemRef.current.offsetWidth - itemRef.current.offsetWidth)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    itemRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${offset}px)`
  }, [offset])

  const shiftSliderRight = () => {
    setOffset(offset => offset + itemRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='page-new-arrivals'>
        <img src={'./static/arrivals_ss19.png'} alt='Arrivals'/>
        <div className='page-new-arrivals__slider_container'>
            <div ref={itemRef} className='page-new-arrivals__slider'>
            <Link to="/itemPage"><Item imgLink='./static/tshirt1.png'/></Link>
            <Item imgLink='./static/tshirt2.png'/>
            <Item imgLink='./static/tshirt3.png'/>

            <Item imgLink='./static/tshirt3.png'/>
            <Item imgLink='./static/tshirt1.png'/>
            <Item imgLink='./static/tshirt2.png'/>
          </div>
          <button onClick={shiftSliderRight}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` of line `` itemRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${offset}px) ``

When I place the breakpoint on this line in goog dev tools, I see it is actually not null and all is fine, once finished rendering, no errors. Why is it so?

Comment: Any producible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), try to upload a codesandbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `const itemRef = React.createRef();` creates a different ref object in each render... To use the same [mutable ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
const itemRef = useRef();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// const itemRef = React.createRef();
const itemRef = useRef(null);
```

And you need to use `if (itemRef.current)` to determine whether the ref is initialized.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

A good article: 
https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-useref-and-react-createref-the-difference-afedb9877d0f